# Trouble importing images into java applet

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a game that I am making for my compsci class and I've been having trouble importing images into my applet for use as a texture. The important classes in this case are my Game.java, Obstacle.java, and Resources.java. Game is my driver class, Obstacle is the object I'm trying to put the image into, and Resources is where I am actually loading the image.

Here are the important parts of each class:

Game.java:

```
Resources image = new Resources(this);

obs = new Obstacle[16]
for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        obs[i] = new Obstacle((i*64), 0, 64, 64);
    }
```

Obstacle.java:

```
private int x, y;  //x pos, ypos
private int w, h; //width, height
Image img;

//Constructor
public Obstacle(int x, int y, int w, int h){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.img = Resources.wall;
}
//paint obstacle
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
    g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
    g.drawRect(x + 1, y + 1, w - 2, h - 2);
    g.drawImage(img, x, y, Resources.game);
}
```

Resources.java:

```
static Image wall;
static URL url;
static Game game;
public Resources(Game ga){
    try{
        url = g.getCodeBase();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    wall = g.getImage(url, "texture.png");
    Resources.game = ga;
}
```

When I run it I don't get any errors but the image also does not appear. I only get the gray squares that are drawn in the paint method. Let me know if any more information is needed.

EDIT: Changed some variable names for clarity

Comment: as long as you're not posting the ACTUALLY essential parts (like `Game.drawImage`) nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: What else do I need to post? Game.java calls Obstacle.paint(g). Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: maybe you should read my comment again ...

Comment: Game.drawImage exists nowhere in my code. I really don't know what you're talking about. Are you referring to g.drawImage in the paint method? That could be confusing. g in that case is Graphics.

Comment: does the `texture.png` have an offset that shifts the actual image away from the position it is inserted ? (that often happens to me if the png is a source of a screenshot)

Comment: This is possible, although I doubt it. How would I go about fixing it if that were the case?